# complex multiplication

Tags: complex-multiplication, abelian-varieties, elliptic-curves

For an abelian variety $A$, it is said to be have $complex \ multiplication$ if $\mathrm{End}(A) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ contains a number filed $F$ of degree $2 \cdot  \mathrm{dim} (A)$. (This is the definition I saw.)

Now assume $A$ is simple. From sec. 1 in Ch. 1 in Lang's book "Complex Multiplication", if $A$ has complex multiplication, then $F = \mathrm{End}(A) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$. (If I understand Thm. 3.1, Lemma 3.2 and Thm. 3.3 correctly.)

But I also saw a paragraph on another book:

http://postimage.org/image/tuoj3u709/

I don't understand this example well. Does it has an imaginary quadratic field? Or these above theorems in Lang's book require the abelian variety being over a characteristic 0 field?

Comment: Most people, include as a definition of complex multiplication that your abelian variety is defined over a field of characteristic zero.

Comment: @stankewicz: Tate proved that abelian varieties over finite fields always have complex multiplication over the ground field (in the sense of the endomorphism algebra over the ground field containing a CM algebra of rank twice the dimension, where "CM algebra" means "product of CM fields"). 

@unknown: That link is wrong: the endomorphism algebra of a ss elliptic curve over an alg. closed field is of rank at most 4, so it cannot be a quaternion algebra over a quadratic field. It is just a quaternion algebra over $\mathbf{Q}$ and *contains* an imaginary quadratic field (even infinitely many).

Comment: @kreck, I felt strange that it is written that "...be a quaternion algebra over a quadratic field...". It is good to know that it contains an imaginary quadratic field and the theorem Tate proved. Could you give the reference for it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @unknown: reference for which?  I mentioned a couple of things.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of definitions of complex multiplication in the literature.

(a) Shimura says that an abelian variety of dimension g has complex multiplication if its endomorphism algebra $End(A)\otimes Q$ contains a field of degree 2g.

(b) Deligne et al. say an abelian variety has complex multiplication if it is a product of abelian varieties with complex multiplication in the sense of Shimura (equivalently, but better, if its Mumford-Tate group is a torus).

(c) Classical algebraic geometers say an abelian variety has complex multiplication if it is acted on by an order in a CM field.

With definition (a), the field is automatically a CM field in characteristic zero, but not otherwise. (A CM field is a quadratic totally imaginary extension of a totally real field.)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that those theorems I listed above require characteristic zero.